# Grouping identical labels and changing text all together - c# / Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a asp.net C# MVC Razor view that allows the user to change units for input fields from metric to imperial.  There are about a dozen labels that all need to be changed at the same time to the same text, no exceptions ("mm" => "inch" and visa verse).

Since the dot net framework requires each element to have unique ID fields I'm trying to find another way to group them all together and change them on the client side.

It seems silly to give each one a unique ID and call each one individually in a if/then statement to switch measurement systems when they are identical.  There has to be a better way.

I attempted to use @ViewBag but I found that javascript can only read the value and can't change it on the client side.

@Html.Label("display_units", "mm", new { id = "lbl_units" })

Thanks for your help and suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your labels a common css class like "display-units".  Then from Javascript code, you can use jQuery to find all labels of that class and change the text:

```
$(".display-units").text('mm');
```

Comment: Simple! That's what I was looking for.  For anyone using this make sure to close the quote. $(".display-units").text('mm');

Answer (score 0):

KnockoutJS was written to solve this kind of problem, ie, binding your viewmodel to your view.

Comment: Good to know.  I'll have to add this to my list of things to learn.

Comment: It's really easy, and helpful at solving this specific problem.  Unlike other frameworks it doesn't try to do EVERYTHING, just 1 thing very well.